# Get credit card information via NFC on Android

Tags: android, nfc, credit-card

Is there some API, which I can use to read the credit card information per NFC on Android device ? Or is it possible to retrieve an ID, which is unique per credit card using some API ?

I have tried the awesome looking [Triangle IO](https://triangle.io/), but it seems that their servers are not working, because I have cloned [their sample github project](https://github.com/triangle-io/applications), and also registered a keys, as they required in [their setup tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20160422115927/http://triangle.io/Blog/20130715). But when I installed the app on my android, it gives me an error: "Invalid application information provided. Double check your app id, access id ..., ".
Then I downloaded their [official sample app](https://web.archive.org/web/20151129092044/https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.triangle.reader.sample) from Google Play. It gives me the same error. Therefore I am assuming, that Triangle IO servers are not working, does anyone using Triangle and can confirm me this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some time ago I found the library for Android, which can read the data from a credit card.
Here it is: https://github.com/devnied/EMV-NFC-Paycard-Enrollment
It's actually the source code for this application: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.devnied.emvnfccard