# Can I get any further information from NFC tag's serial number?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, nfc, cardreader

I want show card number using NFC. But I only can get uid from nfc tag.
I'm using nfc_manager package
and my code like this :

```
void _tagRead() {
    NfcManager.instance.startSession(onDiscovered: (NfcTag tag) async {
      var _tag = tag.data["isodep"]["identifier"]
          .map((e) => e.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0'))
          .join('');
      NfcManager.instance.stopSession();
    });
  }
```

Dont understand what can I do with this id ?

Comment: Do you know any more details about the purpose of the Tag? As it can store data or provide responses in many other different ways. A Nfc Tag id is just designed to allow the system to prevent Tag clash when there are multiple different Tags in range at the same time. So in NFC terms there is no significance of the Tag ID as to what the Tag is meant for.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I want to take card information(card number) via nfc. Is it possible ?

Comment: I'm guessing here that this is some type of payment card that has contact less capabilities? And you are wanting the card number that is used to process payments?

Comment: yes you are right, this is bank app

Answer (score 1):

So with iOS it is not possible to get any details as the [docs iOS NFC](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc?language=objc) it says

> Important
>
> Core NFC doesn't support payment-related Application IDs.

Apple want to keep interactions with NFC enabled bank cards to themselves.

While on Android it is technically possible but complicated and I've not seen anything doing it in flutter (though it should be possible).

You can send and receive the same C-APDU's and R-APDU's as native code used in these examples https://stackoverflow.com/a/34434136/2373819